# Ruby on Rails, sharing data between applications via a central REST API store

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, rest, soa

So here is the basic structure I'm proposing:

Data warehouse (for want of a better word)

- E-commerce online
- Back-end MIS
- etc

So the idea is that I have an Order for example. An order can be created via e-commerce site, or via back-end MIS. Either case the order should filter out to e-commerce to show order to user, and vise versa.

There will be other apps in the future.

So the thinking is, to have a central warehouse that wraps this data in a service API, and then the other apps push / pull to it.

Sound OK? I guess the question is syncing the data. When I create an order, do I push the order at create time to the warehouse, or put it to some queue, or is there some other method to keep all these in sync, assuming, near realtime to realtime sync is required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume your REST server is just another data store. How would each client get updates from a plain old database when needed?

If you had each client poll the data store at regular intervals, that would be one solution.

Comment: Yes that is what I was thinking, I just didn't know if there was a better way, or if I make the data warehouse aware of the apps, and it can push out?

Comment: @brettski Rest is stateless, so you would need something that could store state. A better way would be to implement a messaging service, which would account for message transmission errors and delays; be able to handle client states: appearing (registering) and disappearing (shut down/battery dead/crashed); have capacity to scale to service all clients, etc.

Comment: Thanks Bryan, any suggestions as to a tech stack that may handle that?

Comment: @Brettski Sorry, not really--I'm not familiar with any current stacks. Long ago I worked with [MSMQ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Message_Queuing), but I haven't worked on any projects that needed message queuing since then.